Difference between GW gap and BSE gap. How does net charge play a role?
The energy gap from BSE (GW-BSE) is just the lowest optical excitation energy.
The energy gap from GW, from what I read, is the electron affinity (energy of adding an electron).
I suppose this means the energy change of adding one electron to an infinite system, instead of adding one electron per unit cell (or per electron-wavefunction-supercell from k-mesh).
Is the energy difference between GW gap and BSE gap, mostly due to exciton binding energy? Does the excess charge for GW gap play a big role as well?
The energy of $(N)+1$ electron with $1$ electron in conduction band, should be quite different from the energy of $(N-1)+1$ electron... beside just the exciton binding energy, right?

If you don't get an answer here, consider to ask this on [mattermodeling.se].

Also, please spell out acronyms once (and possibly link to e.g. Wikipedia for the interested reader).
